# get all values inside a container (having nested list and dictionaries)

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, python-3.4

I want to get all values present inside a container (say a `dictionary`). The containers can have nested objects like `dictionary, list, tuples and string` values. Currently I am able to write this code for getting all values, but it does not handle a case where a list item or an object is itself a sequence.

```
def get_all_values_in_container(search_dict):
    value_set = set()
    for key, value in search_dict.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            results = get_all_values_in_container(value)
            for result in results:
                value_set.add(result)
        elif isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
            for items in value: # Will fail if the item itself is a sequence
                value_set.add(items)
        else:
            value_set.add(value)

    return value_set
```

Here is my dummy search_dict

```
    dummy = {'#text': ['Experience with build tools such as GRADLE, ANT or MAVEN; ',
           ' such as ',
           '. Experience with ',
           ' such as ',
           ', Subversion, or GIT. In depth knowledge of ',
           ' platforms Work experience with the following ',
           ', or ',
           '. Experience with build and ',
           '. Education/Certifications ',
           '. '],
 'area': 'RBA5000#LI SO1 Truven Health Analytics\n',
 'education': {'#text': ' degree in ',
               'degree': 'Bachelor s',
               'major': {'#text': 'Computer Science',
                         '@cipcode': '11.0701',
                         '@code': '0402',
                         '@std-major': 'COMPUTER SCIENCE'}},
 'interval': {'#text': ['or ', ' work experience in related field'],
              'area': 'comparable'},
 'skill': ['scripting languages',
           'Perl, UNIX shell',
           'SCM tools',
           'CVS',
           'Windows, UNIX',
           'technologies Oracle, SQL',
           'Informix; Java/J2EE; Cognos',
           'deployment automation tools like Jenkins',
           'preferred_skill',[{'preferred': 'Java/J2EE'}]]}
```

I know it would be a recursive call (may be the same function or another function which itself is recursive). How should I proceed further

Comment: have you the "search_dict" for us to reproduce?

Comment: @AriGold I have pasted it, but it didn't cover the case I am talking about

Comment: whats the expected output? what should be done if the item is a sequence? The example runs without fails.

Comment: @AnuragSharma then add the edge case, this what it's all about :)

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with this solution. As of now it is working fine (at least with my test cases)

```
def get_all_values_in_container(container):
    value_set = set()
    if isinstance(container, (list, tuple, set)):
        for items in container:
            results = get_all_values_in_container(items)
            value_set.update(results)
    elif isinstance(container, dict):
        for key, value in container.items():
            results = get_all_values_in_container(value)
            value_set.update(results)
    else:
        value_set.add(get_processed_item(container))

    return value_set
```

Can anyone give an edge case where it might fail (I am genuinely looking forward at this).